Fetch All Highlighted text from PDF using Document AI
How can I get all high lighted word / text from PDF file using Google Document AI.
I try with Document OCR, Form Parser and etc Processor of document AI
I also try Custom Extractor,  Custom Splitter
I also implemented with Node js

Hi @Nikhil Patel, Cloud you try using Enterprise Document OCR  for your requirement ?. Let me know if this is helpful or not.
